# Brownian motion, rate of large events

Tags: brownian-motion, random-walk

Given the most simple brownian motion:

$$ \dot x(t) = \sigma \eta(t)$$
where $\langle \eta(t)\eta(t')\rangle=\delta(t-t')$, I define as *large event in a time-frame* $\tau$ a portion of the trace $x(t)$ where

$$ x(t+\Delta t)-x(t)>\alpha, \ \mathrm{with}\; \Delta t < \tau.  $$

Basically a *large event* happens when $x(t)$ increases by more than $\alpha$ in a time shorter than $\tau$.

QUESTION: I want to calculate the rate of these *large events*.

MY TENTATIVE ANSWER: Defining as $T_\alpha$ the time at which $x(t+T_\alpha)=x(t)+\alpha$, it is easy to calculate the probability that $T_\alpha<\tau$:
$$ P(T_\alpha<\tau) = \frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2 t}} \int_\alpha^\infty e^{-\frac{y^2}{2\sigma^2 t}} dy.$$

However, this gives me only the probability that $x(t)$ increases more than $\alpha$ in less than $\tau$. But I somehow want to convert this probability into the rate these *large events* happen.
I first thought that the rate $r_{\alpha\tau}$ could be something like
$$ r_{\alpha\tau}=\frac{P(T_\alpha<\tau)}{\tau},$$
but it is easy to show that this is a gross underestimation.

Anybody has a good idea?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my equation is correct, see page 9 of this lecture notes: http://www.columbia.edu/~ks20/FE-Notes/4700-07-Notes-BM.pdf (the factor 2 in the numerator takes into account the possibility of reaching the maximum and then having a dip). I also simulated the process and checked that the predictions of my equation are correct. How did you get your solution?

Comment: (my previous comment was an answer to a comment of somebody that deleted it afterwards...)